# Where is the documentation for MarkdownSharp?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, markdown

I want to use the same functionality on my website as Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange uses with the text editor (in which I am currently typing).

I have seen and downloaded [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp), because Stack Overflow uses this.

But I am **not** able to find the **documentation** for *MarkdownSharp*.

Where can I find the official documentation?

Comment: Given that the most recent commit on that repository was on 2018-12-01, and that SE relatively recently changed over to using [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/), and recently introduced table support, I consider it quite unlikely that repository represents code which SE is actually using at this point.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure there is much documentation apart from the [documentation comments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments). Just have a look at the only public method, [`Transform`](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp/blob/master/src/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#L329), to see what they're supposed to do and how you should call them, and the public properties, e.g. [`EmptyElementSuffix`](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp/blob/master/src/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#L211) to see how they change the behaviour of the class.

To me, it seems pretty straightforward to use, but the maintainers would probably welcome a short tutorial in the [README](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp/blob/master/README.md), so if you figured it out, consider making a pull request.

Comment: but how can we know all available customizable options in markdownSharp ? Only owner of that library can use the full benefit.

Comment: There are only six options, all in the same `#region`. Without comments and whitespace, it's only a couple of hundred lines of code. I'd say it's easier to read than a lot of 'documentation' I've seen on the Net...